# AngularJS in MSIE 8 not running moustache

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Hi all when I have the following code

```
<fieldset ng-repeat="place in getOtherBookedDates()" id="booking-{{$index}}" ng-class="{error: place.errors}" class=" grouping">
            <div class="field" ng-show="place.carParks.length !== 0">
                <label for="booking-{{$index}}-carparks" ng-class="{error: place.errors.selectedCarpark}">Select a car park</label>
                <label for="booking-{{$index}}-carparks" ng-show="place.errors.selectedCarpark" class="error small" >{{getErrorMessage("carpark")}}</label>
</fieldset>
```

it renders, after i add something to the array that is controlling the ng-repeat with

```
{{getErrorMessage("carpark")}}
```

rather than

- no displaying the error message (no tpaying attention to the ng-show of it either)
- not running the javascript contained within the moustache syntax

Can anyone help suggest why?

Answer (score 0):

I've create a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/krTTU/. BTW, on Chrome and IE9 it runs well.
Sorry I can't test IE8 because JSFiddle will crash on it.

Please notice that `id="booking-{{$index}}"` and `for="booking-{{$index}}-carparks"` will not works what you expected.

Comment: but the point is it doesnt work in MSIE8 >MSIE8 and all other browsers are fine